# Keys from dictionary into list and maintain position

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Just trying to create a list from the keys in a dictionary while keep the order of the keys intact. I understood that the order of elements in a python list is persistent.

I have not been able to figure out why the order is changed once I print the content of the list.
The code:

`orderedDict = {'C': 2, 'A': 3, 'B': 3}`

```
orderedList = []
for k,v in orderedDict.items():
    orderedList.append(k)

print(orderedList)
['A', 'B', 'C']

print(type(orderedList))
<class 'list'>
```

I would like the result to be:
`['C', 'A', 'B']`

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: Your code produces the right output.

Comment: When i run your code i get the result you would like `['C', 'A', 'B']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
orderedDict = {'C': 2, 'A': 3, 'B': 3}
orderedList = [key for key in orderedDict.keys()]
```

Comment: How is this different from OP's code? Is it guaranteed that `keys` will iterate over the keys in their insertion order while `items` won't?

Comment: Yes, you are right. In any case the sample code already produced the correct output.

Comment: Running version 3.7. Thanks all for your replies. Yes I re-ran the code in a fresh window and the correct OP was displayed. I might have had a previous variable affecting the original OP.

Answer (score 1):

Since python 3.6, the default `dict` object maintains the order of insertion of items. For previous versions, consider using [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
ordered_dict = OrderedDict([('C', 2), ('A', 3), ('B', 3)])
print(ordered_dict.keys())
# odict_keys(['C', 'A', 'B'])
```

The operations on this is very similar to a regular dict, (i.e you can still assign and get value of keys using indexing `[]`). And remember, this is still not obsolete after py3.6, since it has utility methods for even re-arranging keys such as `move_to_end`